# I can't get XSANE to work in lubuntu 12.04

Tags: sane

XSANE does not see my scanner (part of a Lexmark all-in-one S350). It worked fine,using Ubuntu 10.04. Printing works fine. The all-in-one printer is wireless. The router sees it. I can ping it. I can view it on the LAN via a browser and the local IP address.

I did get a new computer, but I think the difference is that XSANE that installs with Synaptic is now 0.968. The previous setup used 0.966.

Comment: Might need to install the scanner driver.

Comment: Do you still happen to have this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I no longer have the Lexmark printer. Lexmark discontinued the printer around 2018 (or maybe before). They were still making the ink cartridges, but they were getting pretty expensive, so I replaced the printer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://support.lexmark.com/index?filter=UNIVERSAL_PRINTER_DRIVER&page=driversdownloads&linkSelected=node2%5Esubnode2&locale=en&userlocale=EN_US) some .deb driver packages from Lexmark's website. One of which is network scan driver.